# Deployment issues with Visual Studio 2010 asp.net project with Parallels

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, parallels

I currently have Parallels installed on my mac book pro.  I'm running Visual Studio 2010 and created an asp.net web project.  However, when I try to run the application, I can see the server starting

Root URL: http://localhost:50343/WebSite2
Port 50343
Virutal Path: /WebSite2
Physical Path: C:\Users\darewreck\Documents\Visual Studio 20120\WebSites\WebSite2
ASP.NET Version: 4.0.303191

However, in the web browser it never loads and you can see it trying to load the page still.

I think its some configuration I'm missing when your run visual studio on parallels.

Any Advice appreciated,
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just setup boot camp with window 7 and then used parallels to connect to the bootcamp installation of window 7.  This gives you the best of both worlds with windows running natively and being able to run windows and mac at the same time.  However, keep in mind that you will probably need to upgrade your memory and allocate enough to both OS so that its not laggy.